# Endpoint for csv format

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv, nestjs

I am new in NestJS & developing a NestJS project using TypeScript with PostgreSQL database.

I need to export data from database to csv file & implement/expose an endpoint for it.

I did some research found [export to csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-to-csv) library. So decided to use it for my purpose. The end result I want is an endpoint `/report.csv`, when user go there, it would return a csv file.

My controller:

```
@Controller('report')
export class ReportController {
  @Get()
  findAll(@Req() request: Request): string {
      ...
      const dataFromDB = myRepository.fetchDataFromDB();
      const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(dataFromDB);
      csvExporter.generateCsv(dataFromDB);
      // But how can I return the csv as response?
    
  }
}
```

My question is what is the proper way to return csv file as response? Is it correct to do it in controller or is there a better NestJS component for my purpose e.g. interceptor?? Could some one please give suggestions?

(If you have suggestions on other libraries for exporting CSV I would be interested to hear too. Thanks.)